# accessing environment variable from react component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, webpack

I have some non-sensitive data that I need to set to different values based on what environment node runs in `staging` or `production`. I believe accessing something like `process.env.NODE_ENV` will not work within a react component itself, only in a server-side file, hence need a way to somehow pass this down to my react component.

It is simply to show if string "Staging" or "Production" inside the footer component.

Comment: I think you should have the `__DEV__` variable accessible from any component in your application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider using the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin):

> Define free variables. Useful for having development builds with debug
>   logging or adding global constants.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> new webpack.DefinePlugin({
>     VERSION: JSON.stringify("5fa3b9"),
>     BROWSER_SUPPORTS_HTML5: true,
>     TWO: "1+1",
>     "typeof window": JSON.stringify("object")
> })
> ```

Comment: After using the plugin, how do I access the variable  in a component? I tried console.log(Version) but Warning  stated it was undefined.

Comment: I had to set  "globals": { "ENV": false } in .eslintrc. :)

Answer (score 6):

[create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started) creates a React app with environment variable access.

So you could use `process.env.NODE_ENV` in your code without any additional steps.

It also makes any environment variable starting with `REACT_APP_` available to the app.

You get [.env](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) support as well.

## Example

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      users: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(users => this.setState({ users }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1>Env var demo</h1>
        </header>
        <main>
          <ul>
            {this.state.users.map(user => (<li key={user.id}>Name: {user.name}</li>))}
          </ul>
        </main>
        <footer className="App-footer">
          <p>ENVIRONMENT: {process.env.NODE_ENV}</p>
        </footer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Refer to the environment variables documentation: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/