# How to pick the value of an environment variable from Command Prompt in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I want to access the value of an environment variable in my JS file. I tried using the process.end.VAR_NAME method but it renders it as undefined.
I can see the variable and its value by writing the SET command in my terminal but somehow cannot get the already existing value into my project.
Please note that I do not have to initialize my variable, i just need to use an existing one into my project directly.
Also, my project is not based on create-react-app, so is dotenv a possibility to make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [accessing environment variable from react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074470/accessing-environment-variable-from-react-component)

Answer (score 1):

process.env only works for nodeJS, that's why it renders as undefined with react.

I guess you use webpack, if so, you can use webpack.DefinePlugin, which is very usefull to pass environment variable.

You can use it like that:

```
{
    //...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE': JSON.stringify(process.env.MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE)
        })
    ]
    //...
}
```

Thanks to that, the variable 'MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE' is global and can be accessed everywhere in your code.

You can try it by typing console.log(MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE) where you want (in a js file sure).

Comment: Hi, I tried using that, but I still get it as undefined, do I need to add it in package.json and .eslintrc file as well?

Comment: Can you show me your webpack config please ?
And the way you call your variable

Comment: Moreover, if you use eslint, you may need to set this config:
"globals": { "ENV": false }

Comment: I tried using the above method, I still get it as undefined, and I am calling it in my component just as GLOBAL_VARIABLE_NAME

Comment: Can you still please give me your webpack configuration. It is a known solution, you may have forgotten something ^^.